# How can i insert hyperlink into a text with Google slide API (google app script)

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-slides-api

I would like to insert a link into a text (word), but I can't find a way to do the trick. There is no function in the offical Documentation https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element .

I tried something like this:

```
var pageElement = SlidesApp.openById('12hh9vWVhFdj9kH51U-07Rc5yc9gKitJ3f_sr1I38lQQYUDB').getSlides()[0]; pageElement.replaceAllText("Bonjour", "Aurevoir" + **link associated**);
```

The second line is where i can't find a way to do the trick.

How to insert a hyperlink into the text replaced ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To set / update a link you need to use the [Advanced Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides) based on the [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides)

- After [enabling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the advanced service you can use the Slie API method [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) with the request `updateTextStyle`
- This allows you to specify a hyperlink, whereby the id of the shape in which the text of interest is located, its start and end index are required parameters that you have to retrieve in advance
- So, you need to perform two different requests separately - change the text itself and then the hyperlink
- It is important to use [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose) to make sure that the two requests don't timely overlap

- For the latter to work as intended, your script should be alone-standing rather bound to the open Slides document

**Sample code:**

```
function myFunction() {  
  var presentationId = "XXXX";
  var newText = "Aurevoir";
  var oldText = "Bonjour";
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var pageElement = presentation.getSlides()[0]; 
  pageElement.replaceAllText(oldText, newText);
  presentation.saveAndClose();
  var newLink = "www.stackoverflow.com";
  var pageElement = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides()[0]; 
   
  var elements = pageElement.getPageElements();
  var requests =[];
  for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var element = elements[i];
    if(element.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE"){
      var text = element.asShape().getText().find(newText);
      if(text.length > 0){
        var objectId = element.getObjectId();
        for (var j =0; j < text.length; j++){
          var start = text[j].getStartIndex();
          var end = text[j].getEndIndex();
          requests.push(
            {
              updateTextStyle: {
                objectId: objectId,
                textRange: {
                  startIndex: start,
                  endIndex: end,
                  type: "FIXED_RANGE"
                },
                fields: 'link',
                style: {
                  link: {
                    url: newLink
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          );
          Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, presentationId);
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setLinkUrl()` method of `TextStyle`:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setLinkUrl(String)

You can obtain the `TextStyle` from the `TextRange`.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#gettextstyle

For instance, to add a new slide and make its title a link:

```
var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var slide = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.TITLE_AND_BODY);
var title = slide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.TITLE);
var titleText = title.asShape().getText();
titleText.appendText("Link");
titleText.getTextStyle().setLinkUrl("http://test.org");
```

You can also call `getRange()` on the `TextRange` and then call `getTextStyle()` on it if you want to apply the link to a subspan within the text.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getrangestartoffset,-endoffset