# Google Slides API / Apps Script - find URLs and make them into hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

My script pulls rows from a form-populated spreadsheet and applies the values to a slide template.

They submit a Title, Description, and a Link to the resource they are submitting.

I need the "Link", which should be submitted as an URL, to automatically become a hyperlink when the slide is created. Everything I've tried has returned an error. I want to run .setLinkUrl(link) on the previously inserted link text. I just cant get it to stick. Any help would be appreciated.

--below is the function I'm trying to run--

```
    function dataInjectionNN() {
  var dataSpreadsheetUrl = "...spreadsheeturl.urlytypestuff..."
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSpreadsheetUrl);
  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var mathCluster = deck.getName();
  //  Logger.log(mathCluster)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(mathCluster);
  var lastR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range =sheet.getDataRange();
  // Logger.log(range.getLastRow() + " Is the last Column.");
  var values = range.getValues();
  // Logger.log(values);
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var presLength = slides.length;
  var templateSlide = slides[1];
  values.forEach(function(page){
  // run if the presentation has less slides that the number of form entries
    if((presLength-2) < lastR){
      if(page[3] = mathCluster){
       var title = page[9];
       var link = page[10];
       var desc = page[11];
       templateSlide.duplicate();//Duplicate the template page
       slides = deck.getSlides();//update the slides array for indexes and length
       newSlide = slides[2]; //declare the new page to update
       var shapes = (newSlide.getShapes());
       shapes.forEach(function(shape){
            shape.getText().replaceAllText('<<Title>>',title);
            shape.getText().replaceAllText('<<Link>>',link);
            shape.getText().replaceAllText('<<Description>>',desc);
       presLength = slides.length;
       newSlide.move(presLength);
        })
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i insert hyperlink into a text with Google slide API (google app script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62530915/how-can-i-insert-hyperlink-into-a-text-with-google-slide-api-google-app-script)

Comment: It does help to know that I probably need to set up a batchUpdate.

One of the problems I'm running into is that a lot of solutions assume that the objectID is known and the URL is also known. 

I need it to find the object that contains an URL, copy that text, and .setLinkUrl(*the previously copied text*) 

And then do that for every slide in the presentation.