# Insert automatically hyperlink in Slides with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am currently working on the automatic creation of a Google Slides from a Sheets file. I have created a template which, thanks to a script, is duplicated and filled with data present in the Sheets.

Here is what the template looks like :
[image]

Everything works fine except for one column. Indeed, I would like to be able to add a hyperlink in the last part and I am blocked on this subject. I have searched for information on the internet but I can't adapt it to my code.

Indeed, my code replaces all my shapes with hyperlinks when I only want one per slide.

If anyone can help me with that, I would appreciate it very much.

This is my code :

```
function createSlides() {
    // Déclaration des constantes et des variables
    const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName("Importrange");
    const feuilleReport = classeur.getSheetByName("Report des données à diffuser");
    var templateSlide, copy, nomSlide, slideFile, slides, gabaritSlide;
    var tEssais = [], tDonneesReportees = [], nbDonneesReportees = 0;
    var lastRow = 0;

    // Récupération du gabarit
    templateSlide = DriveApp.getFileById("1gYf8X40TePUIJJVR32cSPcLGTxRZ__t9ekeuuv27xgA");

    // Création d'une copie et ajout du nom au Slides
    copy = templateSlide.makeCopy();
    nomSlide = (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1","dd/MM/yyyy")) + " BILAN ESSAIS";
    copy.setName(nomSlide);

    // Ouverture du Slides, récupération des diapositives qui sont à l'intérieur et attribution de la diapositive de référence
    slideFile = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId());
    slides = slideFile.getSlides();
    gabaritSlide = slides[1];

    // Récupération de l'ensemble des données de l'onglet "Importrange"
    tEssais = feuille.getRange("A2:H").getValues();

    // Récupération du nombre de lignes reportées
    tDonneesReportees = feuilleReport.getRange("A2:H").getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== '');
    nbDonneesReportees = tDonneesReportees.length;

    // Suppression des anciens essais
    feuilleReport.deleteRows(1,nbDonneesReportees + 1);

    // Pour chaque ligne du tableau tEssais
    for (let i = 0; i < tEssais.length; i ++){
      // Si l'essai est à diffuser
      if (tEssais[i][7]){
        // La reporter dans l'onglet "Report des données à diffuser"
        feuilleReport.appendRow(tEssais[i]);
      }
    }

    // Récupération de la dernière ligne de l'onglet "Report des données à diffuser"
    lastRow = feuilleReport.getDataRange().getValues().length;

    // Tri des données par site et secteur
    feuilleReport.getRange("B1:B"+ (lastRow)).sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
    feuilleReport.getRange("A1:A"+ (lastRow)).sort({column: 1, ascending: false});

    // Récupération des nouveaux essais à reporter dans le Slides
    tDonneesReportees = feuilleReport.getDataRange().getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== '');

    // Récupération des nouveaux essais à reporter dans le Slides (après ajout si ligne pair ou impair)
    tDonneesReportees = feuilleReport.getDataRange().getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== '');

    // Pour chaque essai, création d'un slide et report des données
    for (let i = 0; i < tDonneesReportees.length; i ++){
      let slide = gabaritSlide.duplicate();
      slide.replaceAllText("{{Site}}", tDonneesReportees[i][0]);
      slide.replaceAllText("{{Secteur}}", tDonneesReportees[i][1]);
      slide.replaceAllText("{{Nom}}", tDonneesReportees[i][2]);
      slide.replaceAllText("{{Contexte}}", tDonneesReportees[i][3]);
      slide.replaceAllText("{{Objectifs}}", tDonneesReportees[i][4]);
      slide.replaceAllText("{{Statut}}", tDonneesReportees[i][5]);
      slide.replaceAllText("{{Lien}}", "LienURL");

      var elements = slide.getPageElements();
      for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j ++){
        var element = elements[j];
        if(element.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE" && element.asShape().getText().find("LienURL")){
          var text = element.asShape().getText();
          text.appendText("Lien");
          text.getTextStyle().setLinkUrl("www.google.com")
        }
      }
    };

    // Suppression de la diapositive qui servait de gabarit
    gabaritSlide.remove();
  }
```

For me, the problem comes from this part:

```
if(element.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE" && element.asShape().getText().find("LienURL")){
```

It can't find the LienURL element. But I don't see how else to do it. Here is what I get as a result :
[image]

I tried an other solution that i saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62530915/how-can-i-insert-hyperlink-into-a-text-with-google-slide-api-google-app-script). But I had an error with my objectID. This is the part of code i tried :

```
  for (let i = 0; i < tDonneesReportees.length; i ++){
     let slide = gabaritSlide.duplicate();
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Site}}", tDonneesReportees[i][0]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Secteur}}", tDonneesReportees[i][1]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Nom}}", tDonneesReportees[i][2]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Contexte}}", tDonneesReportees[i][3]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Objectifs}}", tDonneesReportees[i][4]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Statut}}", tDonneesReportees[i][5]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Lien}}", "Lien");
     var elements = slide.getPageElements();
     var requete = [];
     for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j ++){
       var element = elements[j];
       if (element.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE"){
         var text = element.asShape().getText().find("Lien");
         if (text.length > 0){
           var idObject = element.getObjectId();
           for (let k = 0; k < text.length; k ++){
             var start = text[k].getStartIndex();
             var end = text[k].getEndIndex();
             requete.push({
               updateTextStyle : {
                 objectId : idObject,
                 textRange : {
                   startIndex : start,
                   endIndex : end,
                   type : "FIXED_RANGE"
                 },
                 fields : 'link',
                 style : {
                   link : {
                     url : "www.google.com"
                   }
                 }
               }
             });
             Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests':requete},copy.getId());
           }
         }
       }
     }
   };
```

And i obtain this error :
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my english...

------------ EDIT ------------

This is a minimal reproducible example for a better understanding :

```
function createSlides() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Values");

   // Get Template
   var templateSlide = DriveApp.getFileById("13frZFGs3agqpLnEdXFEcsRadolzZsxeYwgzy2fqOLiw");

   // Create copy of template
   var copy = templateSlide.makeCopy();
   var nameSlide = (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1","dd/MM/yyyy")) + " - SLIDE";
   copy.setName(nameSlide);

   // Open Slide, get all slide and choose what is the template
   var slideFile = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId());
   var slides = slideFile.getSlides();
   var template = slides[1];

   // Get values of Sheet
   var tValues = sheet.getRange("A2:D").getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== '');

   // For each row, create slide
   for (let i = 0; i < tValues.length; i ++){
     // Duplicate template
     let slide = template.duplicate();
     // Add Values
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Site}}", tValues[i][0]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Project}}", tValues[i][1]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Link}}", "Link");
     // Get all of elements in page
     var elements = slide.getPageElements();
     var request = [];
     for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j ++){
       var element = elements[j];
       if (element.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE"){
         var text = element.asShape().getText().find("Link");
         if (text.length > 0){
           var idObject = element.getObjectId();
           for (let k = 0; k < text.length; k ++){
             var start = text[k].getStartIndex();
             var end = text[k].getEndIndex();
             request.push({
               updateTextStyle : {
                 objectId : idObject,
                 textRange : {
                   startIndex : start,
                   endIndex : end,
                   type : "FIXED_RANGE"
                 },
                 fields : 'link',
                 style : {
                   link : {
                     url : tValues[i][1]
                   }
                 }
               }
             });
             Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests':request},copy.getId());
           }
         }
       }
     }
   };
 }
```

This is [my Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oX-s6ymqQ6ic3hd0TXQgtVfqrBCtlYAI2TU3jLOJW68/edit?usp=sharing) and this is [my template's Slide](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13frZFGs3agqpLnEdXFEcsRadolzZsxeYwgzy2fqOLiw/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: You are describing a mail merge process. You may want to try the free [AutoCrat](https://cloudlab.newvisions.org/autocrat) add-on instead of writing your own code. AutoCrat lets you use a Google Slides file as template. Use the **Single document** option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my company doesn't accept add-ons by security...

Comment: Hi, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a copy of the template you are working on?

Comment: Of course lamblichus, I edited my post. You can find in the bottom the minimal repoducible example and the links of my Sheets and template's Slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set the hyperlinks retrieved from the column "C" of the Spreadsheet to `{{Link}}`.

#### Modification points:

- In your template and script, after `Link : {{Link}}` was converted, you are trying to set the hyperlink. In this case, how about replacing and setting both text and hyperlink by using `{{Link}}` as the search text? I thought that by this, your script might be able to be simply a little.
- In your Spreadsheet, it seems that the hyperlinks are put in the column "C". But, you are using `tValues[i][1]`. In this case, I thought that it was `tValues[i][2]`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

In this modification, your bottom script is modified.

#### From:

```
for (let i = 0; i < tValues.length; i ++){
     // Duplicate template
     let slide = template.duplicate();
     // Add Values
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Site}}", tValues[i][0]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Project}}", tValues[i][1]);
     slide.replaceAllText("{{Link}}", "Link");
     // Get all of elements in page
     var elements = slide.getPageElements();
     var request = [];
     for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j ++){
       var element = elements[j];
       if (element.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE"){
         var text = element.asShape().getText().find("Link");
         if (text.length > 0){
           var idObject = element.getObjectId();
           for (let k = 0; k < text.length; k ++){
             var start = text[k].getStartIndex();
             var end = text[k].getEndIndex();
             request.push({
               updateTextStyle : {
                 objectId : idObject,
                 textRange : {
                   startIndex : start,
                   endIndex : end,
                   type : "FIXED_RANGE"
                 },
                 fields : 'link',
                 style : {
                   link : {
                     url : tValues[i][1]
                   }
                 }
               }
             });
             Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests':request},copy.getId());
           }
         }
       }
     }
   };
```

#### To:

```
for (let i = 0; i < tValues.length; i++) {
  let slide = template.duplicate();
  slide.replaceAllText("{{Site}}", tValues[i][0]);
  slide.replaceAllText("{{Project}}", tValues[i][1]);
  slide.getShapes().some(s => {
    var t = s.getText().find("\\{\\{Link\\}\\}");
    if (t.length == 1) {
      t[0].setText("Link").getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(tValues[i][2]);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- When I tested this modified script using your provided sample Spreadsheet and Slides, I confirmed that the script worked. When you change your Spreadsheet and Slides, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [getTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#gettextstyle)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. It works perfectly. Thank you very much Tanaike !!!!

Comment: @devMethodes Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.